# Blog Post with Pictures?

Tags: php, mysql

In an effort to learn more about php and mysql, I have been working through a number of different tutorials and posts on building a simple blog site.  I have a database that holds the necessary, usual suspects (ID, title, author, date, and post). In my php, I query the db, load all the suspects into the van and then echo each one when and where I need them - works brilliantly.

Now I want to go further.  I would like to have the ability to add some images to the blog posts which, right now, are simply typed into the text table of the db.  How do I go about building something like that?  I have been looking everywhere for some kind of hint - basically Googling every combo of "MySQL PHP Blog insert images into post", I can think of.  There are lots of different software options, but I want to understand how to build it from scratch - No Wordpress, Blogger, etc.

I am not trying to allow users to upload images.  I just want to include images in the actual post, so that when I query the db to load the various php divs (title, author, date, and post) the post will include any pictures that I want displayed.  [i.e.  "Here is some sample text that I have been working with and a picture" (picture) "as you can see, the picture above is an example that I have placed in the actual blog post".

How do I get the mysql query to load the post and add the pictures in the appropriate place?  This is not about uploading the images to the server or the database.  This is simply about reading the post's text and including the images for that post in the appropriate spots. I do not want users to be able to upload anything at all, I just want the php page to output the title, the author, the date, and the post (complete with pictures).

Comment: have you tried "php image upload" in Google ?

Comment: you just want to link your post with pictures ? Can your post you actual db schema ?

Comment: Can't you just add a normal `<img>` tag to the post text? Or if you want to strip HTML, come up with some other syntax like `[img:URL]` that you change into an img tag before displaying the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to consider:

- Do you want users to upload images through a form on the site, or are you going to be the only user, and uploading via FTP?
- Are users going to type html into the text editor where they want the picture to show up, or are you going to parse out some kind of simple markup language (such as [img="path/to/image.jpg"] )
- Is the database actually necessary for what you are trying to accomplish?

If your goal is to learn more about PHP, MySQL, and working with images, perhaps something like an image gallery with support for multiple albums may be a more straightforward way to learn what you want to learn. An example of what I am talking about can be found [here](http://www.yourheartphotography.com/photos.php) (Disclosure: this links to the website I am building for my Wife's photography business, but is relevant).

Hope this helps!

::EDIT::
Based upon the update to your question and the comment to my answer, there are two possible solutions I will recommend to you:

The Easy Solution:
Write some HTML in your post referencing the photo based upon where you uploaded it.  tags are easy, and even Blogs such as wordpress will allow you to do this (so it's not a cop-out) :)

The Educational Solution:
In each post, allow for some type of markup indicating where the image needs to be (such as [img]1[/img]... some content ...[img]2[/img]... some more content ), and in your database link each photo ID to each post ID, along with the position you would like the photo to fill in the post. For clarity, that might be:

```
Table photo_in_post:
----------------------------------
|img_id  | post_id | img_position|
|--------|---------|-------------|
| 17     |  4      |  1          |
|--------|---------|-------------|
| 3      |  4      |  2          |
|--------|---------|-------------|
| 4      |  2      |  1          |
|--------|---------|-------------|
```

After grabbing the text of the post, perhaps you could run a query such as:

```
select * from photo_in_post join img on img.id = photo_in_post.img_id where photo_in_post.post_id = 4 order by photo_in_post.img_position;
```

and then loop through your post replacing each occurrence of [img]NUMBER[/img] with an image tag generated based upon the Database result corresponding with the img_position inside the tag. Alternately, you could even loop through the database results and do something along the lines of:

```
str_replace("[img]".$row['img_position']."[/img]", "Generated image tag", $postContents);
```

That would probably be enough to get you started.

Comment: No, I do not want users to be able to upload anything at all, I just want the php page to output the title, the author, the date, and the post (complete with pictures).

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth explanation.  I really appreciate it.  I am going to take the "educational solution" and start working on it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wrestled with in university as it doesn't work as I imagined it would, without writing out the entire code (and saving you all the fun of trial and error) basically you want to have a table in your database that contains the image name and has a reference to the post **ID** so that you can link the two together in your output to screen.

Now there are 2 main problems everyone comes across at first and hopefully these will save you a few hours of head scratching:

Firstly make sure  your form enctype is set to multipart/form-data.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Secondly when you are working with uploaded content it is stored within the $_FILES superglobal array rather than $_POST.

I just did a quick google and pulled out the first result from Tizag that gives a basic overview of php file uploads. It isn't the best but certainly covers the basics.

http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Following that tutorial you should be able to get the image onto your server (providing permissions are set to allow this).

Answer (score 0):

I've thinked a while ago about that and in my opinion, there is one simple solution, but it is fixed. In my way your pictures must be fixed inline in text. In every single blog, "first" picture must be in its own place, then "second" picture must be in its own... ect. ect.

What do I mean?
When you build form which uploads your pictures, build it that first picture will be named "image1", second "image2" or so long... But names must be fixed, so you can write your html code proper.
Then, when you write your blog and select pictures for uploading and when you press the submit button, your php script must build proper folder on your site and then upload pictures in that folder.

When you write your html, then you post a places for your pictures and that one place "calls" image1 from particular folder, second place "calls" image2 from particular folder etc etc... In MySQL table of that blog, beside id, title, date, hour and content of blog, also you must have column name folder as well, which you will call with php code and place in your HTML.

Have I been understandable? Sorry, if my english grammar is not correct or some word also.

That is my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve thought about this before and after some time - this is the only way that seems the simplest and most flexible.

**first let me explain some functionality before I dive into it**

My site (www.nathannoye.com) has a blogging portion. In the admin panel - there is a way to upload a single image for the post header image but I was in the same boat as you wanted to post images in my blog post as well. Seeing as I could upload *one* picture at a time per blog post (and already had a multiple image upload working elsewhere) - why not make a section for specifically uploading assets and using the DB references to mediate between the two.

So this is what my solution was that I’m going to implement in my site redesign:

1. Create a section to upload image assets
2. Allow for multiple image uploads in this section that will upload them to a folder and save the new file name and location in the database. (Maybe even create an image compression script for a smaller res and full res)
3. When creating a blog - have a button that I can click that’ll add HTML markup where ever the carrat is at in my textarea with an empty src tag.
4. This will cause a modal to appear with all the image thumbnails showing up with a small preview in the modal so when I click it - I can make sure it’s the right one
5. Click “ok” will add the image reference to the blog post so when the user requests that blog post - it’ll appear as a normal image in the browser.

Following this strategy - I’m able to reuse those images throughout my site and not worry if that image is stuck to that one blog post.

Not sure if it’s that best way but since I’ll be the only one using it - I don’t really care

Hope this helps!